# All cards run out and all cards in play, still has card draws

Tags: legendary-marvel

Mostly making sure we played this right but I ran into an odd situation recently. My wife had been forced to KO a lot of cards from her deck, while piling up lots of card draw power. She run into a situation where she was playing out her entire deck and still had extra card draws. Usually 3-7 extra draws. We decided that since you just shuffle your discard pile and no card in play enters the discard pile until the turn is over, then she loses those extra draws.

Did we play that right? I looked over the rules but I know I could have easily missed something.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no official or semi-official ruling on a situation like this, but my group played it the same way you did.

The rules state that you reshuffle your discards as soon as you need to draw a new card. As you mention the rules also say that played cards are not cycled into your discards until the end of your turn. The only exception to this I can think of is cards that are discarded to trigger another card's power - these definitely are sent directly to your discard pile.

But if your discards are empty and you have a card that tells you to draw, you can't reshuffle to have a deck at that time, so you can't draw any more cards until after the end of your turn.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't seem like a *ruling* needs to be made; it's just a plain reading of the rules.

Answer (score 1):

In the rules, on page 16 under Special Abilities on Cards, it says, "If a card tells you to do something, and you can't do all of it, then do as much as you can."

So if you play a card that instructs you to draw another card, and there's nothing left to draw from your deck, and nothing left in your discard pile to shuffle into your deck, then you must skip that part. But you can still play the rest of the card to get its other benefits such as recruit & attack points.

Think of it another way: If played cards entered your discard pile and got shuffled into your deck, then in a game like this with a small deck and many draw cards, your turn would never end, because you would just keep re-drawing forever.